SAP ABAP | S_ALR_87013611 Report Painter report to Internal Table
I'm trying to run the standard report S_ALR_87013611 in my ABAP program using submit to get the data in an internal table, but after the submit command the report is displayed in Report Painter format and data is not returned.
I tried different approaches to submit the report without getting output but all attempts were not successful.
I expect suggestions or recommendations to achieve the objective.
REPORT zz_costcenter_3611.

TABLES: csks, cska.

DATA: go_data TYPE REF TO data.
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <gt_data> TYPE ANY TABLE.

PARAMETERS: pkokrs   TYPE kokrs OBLIGATORY DEFAULT '1000',  "Company Code
            pgjahr   TYPE gjahr OBLIGATORY ,                " Fiscal Year
            pperbl_f TYPE perbl,                            " period low
            pperbl_t TYPE perbl,                            "period high
            pversn   TYPE versn OBLIGATORY DEFAULT '0'.     "plan version
PARAMETERS: pksgru   TYPE ksgru. "cost center Group
PARAMETERS: p_kostl  TYPE csks-kostl NO-DISPLAY.
SELECT-OPTIONS: so_kostl FOR p_kostl.
PARAMETERS: pkagru   TYPE kagru.  "Cost element group
PARAMETERS: p_kstar  TYPE cska-kstar NO-DISPLAY.
SELECT-OPTIONS: so_kstar FOR p_kstar.

START-OF-SELECTION.

  cl_salv_bs_runtime_info=>set( EXPORTING display  = abap_false
                                          metadata = abap_false
                                          data     = abap_true ).

  SUBMIT gp4qlqkh46vzj3p1a40a23s3hjg300
          WITH $1kokre EQ pkokrs
          WITH $1gjahr EQ pgjahr
          WITH $1periv EQ pperbl_f
          WITH $1perib EQ pperbl_t
          WITH $1verp EQ pversn
          WITH $1koset EQ pksgru
          WITH _1koset IN so_kostl
          WITH $1kstar EQ pkagru
          WITH _1kstar IN so_kstar
    AND RETURN.

  TRY.
      cl_salv_bs_runtime_info=>get_data_ref(
        IMPORTING r_data = go_data ).
      ASSIGN go_data->* TO <gt_data>.

    CATCH cx_salv_bs_sc_runtime_info ##NO_HANDLER.
      MESSAGE 'Unable to retrieve ALV data' TYPE 'E'.
  ENDTRY.


It is not possible to capture the data screen from that report to an understandable internal table. I believed that the best option is to verify the export to memory of that report. It seems to export the data tables.
